# ( Qt4 compile)error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, linux, qt, compiler-errors

When i compile the src code of Qt4.8.1,an error has occurred:

```
../3rdparty/libpng/pngerror.c:324:48: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
             for (; i<(sizeof msg)-1 && parm != '\0' && parm < pend; ++i)
```

Help me please,my system is ubuntu18.04.
Thanks.

Comment: Since the file is called `pngerror.c` it seems you are supposed to use a C compiler.

Comment: When I found that line of code in an internet search it read `i<(sizeof msg)-1 && *parm != '\0' && parm < pend` which makes much more sense. See [here](https://fossies.org/linux/libpng/pngerror.c)

Comment: You are right,the error disappeared after I revised it.

Comment: But there is another mistake:

Comment: widgets/qdialogbuttonbox.cpp:260:1: error: narrowing conversion of ‘2147483650’ from ‘unsigned int’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
 };
 ^
widgets/qdialogbuttonbox.cpp:260:1: error: narrowing conversion of ‘2415919104’ from ‘unsigned int’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
widgets/qdialogbuttonbox.cpp:260:1: error: narrowing conversion of ‘2147483649’ from ‘unsigned int’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]

Comment: Hi please post your updates as edits to the question! Also, what are the types of `i`, `parm` and `pend`? It will also be good if you could post relevant code surrounding the for loop